# Create array from string using php

Tags: php, string

I have a string like below

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;test@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found
```

I need to get each value as an associative array like

```
array('Final-Recipient'=>'rfc822;test@example.com',
      'Action'=>'failed',
      'Status'=>'5.1.1',....)
```

I was try with explode function,But it don't give result expected.

```
    $result = array();
    $temp =  explode(';',$message);
    foreach($temp as $value)
    {
     $temp2   = explode(':',$value);
     $result[$temp[0]] = $result[$temp[1]];     
    }
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. Otherwise we assume you didn't and just want us to do your work for you.

Comment: @JohnConde I will post soon,Please wait

Comment: Hint: why are you exploding by `;` when it's obviously not the delimiter in your input data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    $str = 'Final-Recipient: rfc822;test@example.com
    Action: failed
    Status: 5.1.1
    Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found';
        $res = array ();
        foreach (explode (PHP_EOL, $str) as $e) {
            $t = explode (':', $e);
            $res[trim($t[0])] = trim($t[1]);
        }
        var_dump($res);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you split the lines by `:` followed by space instead of just `:`. Otherwise you should trim `$t[1]`.